# How can I select items with Linq by Date while ignoring Time portion of a DateTime property?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a list of objects with a DateTime parameter.

I would like to use LINQ to query this list and return entries by date but ignoring the Time portion

So I would like to select any entry that occurs at any time on 08-10-2012.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this snippet for in-memory queries:

```
var theDate = new DateTime(2012, 08, 10);
var entriesOnTheDate = list.Where(item => item.DateTimeField.Date.Equals(theDate));
```

For querying against SQL Server data source, you can use [`SqlFunctions.DatePart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487171.aspx) to extract the day, the month, and the year, and compare them separately.

```
var entriesOnTheDate = dbContext
    .EntriesWithDateTimeField
    .Where(item => SqlFunctions.DatePart("Year", item.DateTimeField) == 2012
                && SqlFunctions.DatePart("Month", item.DateTimeField) == 8
                && SqlFunctions.DatePart("Day", item.DateTimeField) == 12);
```

Comment: Testing only the date is really easier. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
 entries.Where( e => e.Property.Date == new DateTime( 2012, 08, 10 ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a range of times that covers your entire day:

```
entries.Where(e => e.Property.Date >= new DateTime(2012, 08, 10) 
                   && e.Property.Date < new DateTime(2012, 08, 11));
```

Answer (score 1):

what about using EntityFunctions.TruncateTime ( EF 6 onwards)

```
var result = context.Employees
.Where(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.LoginDate) ==DateTime.Today)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Namespace: System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.TruncateTime